# Is it possible to create zoom-independent line on html5 canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I want to create a zoom-independent line (browser zoom, etc.) on HTML5 canvas such that the line will remain at 1 screen-pixel width even if you zoom into the canvas. I kind of have photoshop's vector tool in my mind, the vector line is independent of the navigation zoom.

Comment: Maybe you could find a way to calculate the user's zoom and then divide the width by that.

Comment: There are no half-pixels - which is why SVG is used to scale.